# nth-child colors something wrong

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to make each li a different color using `nth-child();`
This is my CSS:

```
header ul a:nth-child(1) {
    color: #8cf;
}
header ul a:nth-child(2) {
    color: #f8c;
}
header ul a:nth-child(3) {
    color: #8fc;
}
header ul a:nth-child(4) {
    color: #b9b;
}
header ul a:nth-child(5) {
    color: #c8c;
}
```

This is my html:

```
  <body>
<div id="main">
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="forums.html">Forums</a></li>
      <li id="iamhere"><a href="instruction.html">Instruction</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Everything is purple even though I don't have any reference of purple anywhere.

Comment: Your anchors are only children of the list items, so nth-child is doing it's job. Each anchor has no siblings, which is what nth-child looks for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `nth-child()` on the `li` tags, your `a` tags don't have any siblings. The purple color is your browsers default color for already visited links.

```css
header ul li:nth-child(1) a {
  color: #8cf;
}
header ul li:nth-child(2) a {
  color: #f8c;
}
header ul li:nth-child(3) a {
  color: #8fc;
}
header ul li:nth-child(4) a {
  color: #b9b;
}
header ul li:nth-child(5) a {
  color: #c8c;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="forums.html">Forums</a>
        </li>
        <li id="iamhere"><a href="instruction.html">Instruction</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Why is it targeting the list dots?

Comment: Because I just selecte the `li` tags. I've updated my answer to the `a` tags. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

The nth-child needs to be an HTML element with a parent and siblings.  In this case, the qualifying element is <LI> and each one has precisely one <a> element.  The CSS needs tweaking so that each LI element is selected and styling applied to its solitary A element.

```css
header ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    color: #8cf;
}
header ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    color: #f8c;
}
header ul li:nth-child(3) a {
    color: #9ff;
}
header ul li:nth-child(4) a {
    color: #000;
}
header ul li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: #c8c;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="forums.html">Forums</a></li>
      <li id="iamhere"><a href="instruction.html">Instruction</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Note: I changed the colors pertaining to the last two <a> tags just to dramatically highlight the results.

Also, with respect to the browser changing the link color, when the CSS using the :nth-child is applied accordingly, then the browser adheres to the specified color even when the link is a visited one.

Incidentally, if you wish for the bullet color to match its respective link, the CSS needs only minor modification:

```
header ul li:nth-child(1),  li:nth-child(1) a {
    color: #8cf;
}
header ul li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(2) a {
    color: #f8c;
}
header ul li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(3) a {
    color: #9ff;
}
header ul li:nth-child(4), li:nth-child(4) a {
    color: #000;
}
header ul li:nth-child(5), li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: #c8c;
}
```

See live code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gn4n97v9/1/).

If the HTML were re-written to contain multiple links within a block such as a P element, then the A element would qualify for nth-child selection as exemplified [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gn4n97v9/18/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding header "ul li:nth-child(1) a" will make different color anchor tags.

Added code here [View Code](http://codeamaze.com/code-beautifier/html-beautifier/iQpJSlYAkMs=)